# How to only return a single image row from multiple joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some sql that gathers product information. It also retrieves images from joined tables. Sometimes a product will have more than one image (sometimes none) and this causes duplicates in the results. How can I change this query to only return a single image (or no images) from the joined image tables - image_d,image_p,image_t ?

```
SELECT 
   products_categories.categoryid, 
   products.productid, 
   products.product, 
   products.descr, 
   products.rating, 
   products.title_tag, 
   images_d.image_path AS imaged, 
   images_p.image_path AS imagep, 
   images_t.image_path AS imaget, 
   clean_urls.clean_url 
FROM products_categories 
INNER JOIN products ON products_categories.productid = products.productid 
LEFT JOIN images_d ON products.productid = images_d.id 
LEFT JOIN images_p ON products.productid = images_p.id 
LEFT JOIN images_t ON products.productid = images_t.id 
LEFT JOIN clean_urls ON products.productid = clean_urls.resource_id 
WHERE  products_categories.categoryid = 265 
AND products_categories.main = 'Y' 
AND products.forsale = 'Y'
ORDER  BY productid
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that there's more than one image in a given image_x table. You can use [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to shoehorn multiple values into one [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) column:

```
SELECT
   products_categories.categoryid, 
   products.productid, 
   products.product, 
   products.descr, 
   products.rating, 
   products.title_tag, 
   group_concat(images_d.image_path) AS imaged, 
   group_concat(images_p.image_path) AS imagep, 
   group_concat(images_t.image_path) AS imaget, 
   clean_urls.clean_url 
FROM products_categories 
INNER JOIN products ON products_categories.productid = products.productid 
LEFT JOIN images_d ON products.productid = images_d.id 
LEFT JOIN images_p ON products.productid = images_p.id 
LEFT JOIN images_t ON products.productid = images_t.id 
LEFT JOIN clean_urls ON products.productid = clean_urls.resource_id 
WHERE products_categories.categoryid = 265 
AND products_categories.main = 'Y'
AND products.forsale = 'Y'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,10
ORDER BY productid
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I still get duplicate productid's returned.

Comment: @stackasker: Could it be because the duplicate products belong to more than one category?

Comment: @AndriyM: No, that's not it. When I change the proposed query to group by 2 it seems to return the correct results though. More sleep, more testing.

Comment: @stackasker: Then maybe it's `clean_urls`. I mean, it may contain multiple references to the same product, in which case you could apply `group_concat` to it, like it is done with image paths. Anyway, if you end up grouping by 2 only, you may simply get rid of `group_concat`s, because MySQL will then return only one value (picked arbitrarily) per product for each of those columns. And I would then recommend you to read [this manual page about hidden columns in GROUP BY queries in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) (if you haven't already done that).